# Passing data from view to express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm looking on for some guidance on the following problem. I'm attempting to pass a string to the server from a jade view. The val is being returned on the frontend but when I try to store it in the object I am being returned `[object Object]`.

I believe it's breaking around the parameters variable but I can't work out why.

```
$(function(){
  $('#search').on('paste', function(){
    console.log('key up');

    setTimeout(function () {
      var linkURL =  $('#search').val();
      console.log(linkURL)

      // EVERYTHING BREAKS HERE
      var parameters = { search: $(this.target).val() };
      console.log('p' + parameters)
      $.get( '/searching',parameters, function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
      });
    }, 100);

  });
});
```

View

```
extends layout

block content
  .container
    h1 London Plans
    form(method='post' action='/submit', class='plans', id='plans')
      .form-group
        label Do you have a link?
        input.form-control(name='search', id='search' type='text', required='required')
```

I think the express code is correct, the `console.log` returns `undefined`, assuming because the object is broken.

```
app.get('/searching', function(req, res){
 // input value from search
 var val = req.query.search;
 console.log('val equals =' + ' ' + val);

// testing the route
// res.send("WHEEE");

});
```

Any pointers in the right direction to debug the object would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show what `console.log('p' + parameters)` prints? Could you also elaborate exactly what returns `[object Object]`?

Comment: The `parameters` variable is returning '[object Object]'. So the `console.log('p' + parameters)` is where I'm seeing the error.

Comment: Try `console.log('p: ', parameters)` Notice the comma instead of plus sign.

Comment: Nifty trick, search is undefined. `p:  Object {search: undefined}`

Comment: this probably doesn't refer to this in `on('paste', function()` but in `setTimeout(function ()`. Try storing this from paste into var like `var self = this` then using that self inside timeout function like `$(self.target)`. See if that helps? Also try printing the this.target? Is it what you expect it to be (use comma)?

Comment: Still coming up as undefined unfortunately, I tried printing it to and it was undefined. The expected behaviour is to take the string from the input, store it in an object and send that data to a server side function.

Comment: Try to print `console.log($(this.target));` right after `console.log('key up');` Then inspect the this.target object: is it a list or a single object? Does it have the correct value in it? You could also try to change `$(this.target).val()` to `$('#search').val()` as it is an id. If you get a list of items, then just change to `$(this.target)[0].val()`.

Comment: `$('#search').val()` did the trick. Could have sword I originally tried that! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `var parameters = { search: $(this.target).val() };` with `var parameters = { search: $('#search').val() };`. The `this` variable inside `setTimeout()` refers to different object than `this` inside `on()`.

You could alternatively replace `{ search: $(this.target).val() }` with `{ search: linkURL }` as you already save the result of `$('#search').val()` into `linkURL`.

Also see jQuery API for on() function: http://api.jquery.com/on/

The examples use `this` pointer "as it is" instead of writing `this.target`. For example in your case you could write: `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this.target).val()`. Move line `var linkURL =  $('#search').val();` above `setTimeout` line and change it to `var linkURL =  $(this).val();`. Then replace `{ search: $(this.target).val() }` with `{ search: linkURL }`.

(The `this.target` is the way to obtain the target element from an event object but here we do not have one.)